# How to filter parts of image using python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a program to give some effects to an image. Now, I wanted to apply the effects only to some parts of the image. I tried to change the range, but somehow the other parts of the picture only appeared as black image. I wanted to make the effects appear only to some parts of the image, while the other parts remain the same (original picture). Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import floor
from PIL import Image

print('Please insert the effect of your choice:')
print('1. No effect')
print('2. Edge detection')
print('3. Image Sharpening')
print('4. Image Blurring')
ch=(input('Insert the number of choice: '))
if ch!='1' and ch!='2' and ch!='3' and ch!='4':
    print('No effect available')
    ch=(input('Insert the number of choice: '))
    
im=Image.open('unnamed.jpg')
im.convert("RGB")
imagematrix=np.array(im)
(Nx,Ny,M)=imagematrix.shape

if ch=='1':
    kernel=np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])
elif ch=='2':
    kernel=np.array([[-1,-1,-1],[-1,8,-1],[-1,-1,-1]])
elif ch=='3':
    kernel=np.array([[0,-1,0],[-1,5,-1],[0,-1,0]])
elif ch=='4':
    kernel=np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])

div=np.sum(kernel)

if div==0:
   div=1
Nxnew=int(0.5*Nx)
imfil=np.zeros([Nx,Ny,M], dtype=int)
for j in range (0,M):
    for row in range (1, Nxnew-1):
        for column in range(1, Ny-1):
            a=0
            for b in range(-1,2):
                for k in range(-1,2):
                    a+=imagematrix[row+b,column+k,j]*kernel[b+1,k+1]
                imfil[row,column,j]=floor(abs(a/div))
plt.imshow(imfil)
plt.show()
```

How do I apply the effects to only some parts of the picture (ex: the filters only applied to half of the pictures, while the other half is the original picture with no filter)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DSteman How can I apply the effects to only some parts of the picture?

Comment: Hard to say. Can you make a minimal reproducable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You could use something like codesandbox. Please post the link in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is initializing the destination image with the source image, and modify only the relevant part of the destination image.

In your code, replace:

```
imfil=np.zeros([Nx,Ny,M], dtype=int)
```

With:

```
imfil = imagematrix.copy()
```

---

Assuming the type of `imagematrix` is `np.uint8`, you need to make sure to clip the values you are storing in `imfil` to range [0, 255] (range of `uint8`).

Replace:

```
imfil[row, column, j] = floor(abs(a / div))
```

With:

```
imfil[row, column, j] = max(min(round(a / div), 255), 0)  # round and limit to [0, 255]
```

Notes:

- Applying `abs` looks like a mistake.
- `round` is more accurate than `floor` (but it's not critical).

---

I used `chelsea.png` image from [here](http://danielballan.github.io/photomosaic/docs/tutorial.html) as an input image.

Here is a complete code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import floor
from PIL import Image

# print('Please insert the effect of your choice:')
# print('1. No effect')
# print('2. Edge detection')
# print('3. Image Sharpening')
# print('4. Image Blurring')
# ch = (input('Insert the number of choice: '))
# if ch != '1' and ch != '2' and ch != '3' and ch != '4':
#     print('No effect available')
#     ch = (input('Insert the number of choice: '))
ch = '3'  # Fix to '3' for testing.

im = Image.open('chelsea.png') #im = Image.open('unnamed.jpg')
im.convert("RGB")
imagematrix = np.array(im)
(Nx, Ny, M) = imagematrix.shape

if ch == '1':
    kernel = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
elif ch == '2':
    kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 8, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
elif ch == '3':
    kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]])
elif ch == '4':
    kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])

div = np.sum(kernel)

if div == 0:
    div = 1
Nxnew = int(0.5 * Nx)

# Instead of filling imfil with zeros, initialize imfil with imagematrix.
imfil = imagematrix.copy()  # np.zeros([Nx, Ny, M], dtype=int)
for j in range(0, M):
    for row in range(1, Nxnew - 1):
        for column in range(1, Ny - 1):
            a = 0
            for b in range(-1, 2):
                for k in range(-1, 2):
                    a += imagematrix[row + b, column + k, j] * kernel[b + 1, k + 1]
                #imfil[row, column, j] = floor(abs(a / div))  # Why floor(abs(a / div)) ?
                imfil[row, column, j] = max(min(round(a / div), 255), 0)  # round and limit to [0, 255]
plt.imshow(imfil)
plt.show()
```

---

Result:

`im` (Input image):
[image]

`imfil` (Output image):
[image]